# Can't add RealmSwift pod to a React Native project "Undefined symbol: protocol description for Swift.Identifible ... for libRealmSwift"

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, realm

I've discovered its not possible to add RealmSwift to an Xcode project which was auto-generated by React Native.

If I manually create an Xcode project and then create a pod file and add the following lines to it, then everything builds successfully:

```
  pod 'Realm', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'RealmSwift', :modular_headers => true
```

However if these same lines are added to the existing podfile for a React Native project then when compiling there is the following error

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "protocol descriptor for
> Swift.Identifiable", referenced from:
> l_got.$ss12IdentifiableMp in libRealmSwift.a(Combine.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

The full podfile is

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

workspace 'AwesomeProject'

target 'AwesomeProject' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'Realm', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'RealmSwift', :modular_headers => true

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

How can I use RealmSwift in a React Native app?

(The modular_headers qualifiers are added because without them there is the following error during pod install:

> [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static
> libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `RealmSwift` depends upon `Realm`, which does not define
> modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is
> necessary to import them from Swift when building as static
> libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your
> Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular
> dependencies.)

(Note: I DO NOT want to use the ReactNativeRealm component, firstly this only adds a Javascript version of Realm, secondly I only want to use Realm in the iOS version of the app, not the Android version)